# Looping multiple elements in independent regression function

Tags: python

my code can find the linear regression equation from a searched term in Google Trends. Here is the working code:

```
from pytrends.request import TrendReq

google_username = "xxx@gmail.com"
google_password = "xxx"
path = ""

keyword = ["stackoverflow"]
pytrend = TrendReq(google_username, google_password, custom_useragent='')
pytrend.build_payload(kw_list=keyword, timeframe='today 5-y', geo='MX')

def regression(x):

    df = pytrend.interest_over_time()[x]

    df.insert(0, 'x', range(1, 1 + len(df)))
    df.columns = ['x', 'y']
    x,y = df['x'], df['y']

    x_raya = []
    cuad = []
    x_mean = x.mean()
    y_raya = []
    y_mean = y.mean()

    for xs in x:
        x_raya.append(xs - x_mean)
        cuad.append(xs**2)

    for ys in y:
        y_raya.append(ys - y_mean)

    mult = [x_raya[i]*y_raya[i] for i in range(len(x_raya))]

    b1 = sum(mult)/sum(cuad)
    b0 = y_mean-(b1*x_mean)

    print("The equation is %s + %s x" % (b0,b1))

regression(keyword)

Out: The equation is 41.1203123741 + 0.010605085267 x
```

My problem is whenever I try to add more words to our keyword:

```
from pytrends.request import TrendReq

google_username = "xxx@gmail.com"
google_password = "xxx"
path = ""

keyword = ["stackoverflow", "reddit"]
pytrend = TrendReq(google_username, google_password, custom_useragent='')
pytrend.build_payload(kw_list=keyword, timeframe='today 5-y', geo='MX')

def regression(x):

    df = pytrend.interest_over_time()[x]

    df.insert(0, 'x', range(1, 1 + len(df)))
    df.columns = ['x', 'y']
    x,y = df['x'], df['y']

    x_raya = []
    cuad = []
    x_mean = x.mean()
    y_raya = []
    y_mean = y.mean()

    for xs in x:
        x_raya.append(xs - x_mean)
        cuad.append(xs**2)

    for ys in y:
        y_raya.append(ys - y_mean)

    mult = [x_raya[i]*y_raya[i] for i in range(len(x_raya))]

    b1 = sum(mult)/sum(cuad)
    b0 = y_mean-(b1*x_mean)

    print("The equation is %s + %s x" % (b0,b1))

regression(keyword)

Out: ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 3 elements, new values have 2 elements
```

Any suggestions on how to make the code iterate through various elements in a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asking how to iterate a list?

```
# Generalize list variable name
keyword_list = ["stackoverflow", "reddit"]

# Skip down to where you call your regression function
...

# And...use a basic iteration
for keyword in keyword_list:
    regression(keyword)
```

Although, without seeing the code for your `pytrend.build_payload()` code, I don't know if that can accept and handle a list, or if it needs to be part of the iteration. To be safe, what you should probably do is rearrange your code like so:

```
from pytrends.request import TrendReq

google_username = "xxx@gmail.com"
google_password = "xxx"
path = ""

def regression(x):

    df = pytrend.interest_over_time()[x]

    df.insert(0, 'x', range(1, 1 + len(df)))
    df.columns = ['x', 'y']
    x,y = df['x'], df['y']

    x_raya = []
    cuad = []
    x_mean = x.mean()
    y_raya = []
    y_mean = y.mean()

    for xs in x:
        x_raya.append(xs - x_mean)
        cuad.append(xs**2)

    for ys in y:
        y_raya.append(ys - y_mean)

    mult = [x_raya[i]*y_raya[i] for i in range(len(x_raya))]

    b1 = sum(mult)/sum(cuad)
    b0 = y_mean-(b1*x_mean)

    print("The equation for keyword {} is {} + {} x".format(keyword, b0,b1))

keyword_list = ["stackoverflow", "reddit"]

for keyword in keyword_list:
    pytrend = TrendReq(google_username, google_password, custom_useragent='')
    pytrend.build_payload(kw_list=keyword, timeframe='today 5-y', geo='MX')

    regression(keyword)
```